# Swift rewriting init(format: String, _ arguments: CVarArg...)

Tags: swift, switch-statement, protocols, control-flow

I'm trying to rewrite the standard String(format, arguments) method found in foundation which takes a string and replaces all values containing %i with ints and %@ with strings and a whole range of types. https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/string/3126742-init

Since I don't know c I converted the initializer from

```
init(format: String, _ arguments: CVarArg) {
```

to

```
init(format: String, _ arguments: [Any]) {
```

Now I got it working for Ints using this in a String Extension

```
  init(format: String, _ arguments: [Any]) {
            var copy = format
            for argument in arguments {
                switch argument {
                case let replacementInt as Int:
                    String.handleInt(copy: &copy, replacement: String(replacementInt))
                default:
                    self = format
                }
            }
        self = copy
    }

private static func handleInt(copy: inout String, replacement: String) {
```

but since I would like this to work for all values I'm trying to use the switch to look for type Any that has the Protocol of LosslessStringConvertible required to convert to a string using the String(value) initializer.

```
     init(format: String, _ arguments: [Any]) {
        var copy = format
        for argument in arguments {
            switch argument {
            case let replacementInt as LosslessStringConvertible:
                String.handleAnyValue(copy: &copy, replacement: String(replacementInt))
            default:
                self = format
            }
        }
    self = copy
}
```

However, I get the following error when applying String(replacementInt)

> Protocol type 'LosslessStringConvertible' cannot conform to
>   'LosslessStringConvertible' because only concrete types can conform to
>   protocols

**Bonus**
A bonus would be if I could do this without importing any library and simply writing using swift.

Comment: The error is quite clear. The argument of the `String()` initializer must be a concrete type, not a protocol.

Comment: How can I make a concrete type of Any which could be Int or String or is it simply not possible and I have to typecast to Int. @vadian

Comment: Why not a second case? `case let replacementInt as Int` and `case let replacementString as String`. The parameter `replacement` in `handleAnyValue` can be declared as `LosslessStringConvertible` or as generic `T<LosslessStringConvertible>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could make conformance to `LosslessStringConvertible` to be a requirement for arguments:

```
init<S: LosslessStringConvertible>(format: String, _ arguments: [S])
```

This would support all types that conform that protocol out of the box (and allows to extend other types to conform this protocol):

```
var x: String  = String(format: "%i %@", 5, "five")
print(x) // prints "5 five"
```

Limitation with this solution is that for instance type that doesn't conform to LosslessStringConvertible will cause an error. For example:

```
class Z {}
let z = Z()
var y: String = String(format: "%i %@ %@", 5, "five", z) // Compilation error: Argument type 'Z' does not conform to expected type 'CVarArg'
```